# Flutter MapBox Error - Unauthorized 401 error when building app for Android

Tags: android, flutter, mapbox-gl, flutter-build

In my project I use `mapbox_gl: ^0.14.0`.

When running flutter build aar command it fails with:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mapbox_gl:generateDebugRFile'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':mapbox_gl:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.6.2.
     Required by:
         project :mapbox_gl
      > Could not resolve com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.6.2.
         > Could not get resource 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-sdk/9.6.2/mapbox-android-sdk-9.6.2.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-sdk/9.6.2/mapbox-android-sdk-9.6.2.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
   > Could not resolve com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.6.2.
     Required by:
         project :mapbox_gl > com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-annotation-v9:0.9.0
      > Could not resolve com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.6.2.
         > Could not get resource 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-sdk/9.6.2/mapbox-android-sdk-9.6.2.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-sdk/9.6.2/mapbox-android-sdk-9.6.2.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
   > Could not resolve com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.6.2.
     Required by:
         project :mapbox_gl > com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-localization-v9:0.12.0
         project :mapbox_gl > com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-offline-v9:0.7.0
      > Could not resolve com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.6.2.
         > Could not get resource 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-sdk/9.6.2/mapbox-android-sdk-9.6.2.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-sdk/9.6.2/mapbox-android-sdk-9.6.2.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 30s
```

Gradle task assembleAarDebug failed with exit code 1.

Also flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.0, on macOS 12.0.1 21A559 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
```

I think it's the problem with secret token since it gives me Unauthorized 401 from server.

I made sure that I put it in my global (not project) gradle.properties the secret key like this:
`MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN=sk.eyJ1Ij...`
I saw in another thread that maybe it should be MAPBOX_DOWNLOAD_TOKEN instead of MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN
but it did not help.

My secret token has all PUBLIC SCOPES ticked and DOWNLOADS:READ ticked in SECRET SCOPES

So maybe my project simply not reading it but I don't know why.

Comment: Hello,
Have you found any solution for that? I have the same issue arrive.

Answer (score 0):

You can find documentation of Mapbox GL for android here:
https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/.

**As said by the mapbox_gl plugin developers, this is community driven not an official Mapbox product.**

So, do only the https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/#configure-credentials part of the documentation for the flutter android project.

- **Create a secret access token** with the `Downloads:Read` scope.
- **Configure your secret token** in android/gradle.properties as `MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN=YOUR_SECRET_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN`
- **Configure permissions** in app/source/main/AndroidManifest.xml as:

  ```
  <!-- Always include this permission -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

  <!-- Include only if your app benefits from precise location access. -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  ```
- **Keep in mind** to provide the same secret key in the `accessToken` property of the `MapboxMap` widget in your project.